# can i create website theme using YUI?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, yui

Hi I want to know what is the easiest way to create smooth,simple and attractive,
 light weight theme for website ?
  so I have confusion in choosing many css, js framework.
  can any body tell me which is better and best to create theme ??

Answer (score 0):

it depends on many factors such as what type of theme you want to create. If the theme is just going to be dealing with UI Controls, Then checkout

jquery ui at http://jqueryui.com/ as it provides excellent themese for you.

Since you mentioned CSS you should also check

Blue Print CSS Framework

as it comes with a huge variety of styles that you can add readily.

You can also download some HTML 5 light weight themes that are compatible with mobile devices also and then you can customize them to their content.

http://creativecan.com/2012/05/html5-and-css3-templates/

Check that out as well.

Comment: You can use YUI for creating Ui Widgets and Tool kits. It is easy to create stuff like drag and drop, data grids etc using YUI